# Android AchartEngine: maintain position after updating

Tags: android, scroll, zooming, updates, achartengine

I'm trying to plot a chart, representing the rate of the download. Well i can display in real time the rate like in the picture :

[image]

But every time there is an update in the plot ,it comes back to the begining of the chart, which is not confortable to the user. And for example if i zoom to see better ,if there is an update it starts from the begining.

So how can i maintain my last position ,if i scroll or i zoom the chart ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember the chart minimum X and Y values and apply them back after a repaint. In order to save the values, you would do:

```
double x = renderer.getXAxisMin();
```

and to apply it back:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(x);
```